# how to get the variable of one method without using getattr

Tags: python

I want to get the variable of one method from another method in same class.when i use getattr am getting the return value of that method but i need to get the value of particular variable of that method.I mentioned the details below

```
class hai():
  def hel(self):
     a=10
     b=20
     c=a+b
     print c
 def hw(self):
     d=10
     print d
```

In the above program i need to access the value of variable b in the method hw.I can't able to get the particular variable value.

Comment: If you "need" to access `b` inside `hw` from the outside, you should probably rethink your design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it to the class, like this

```
class hai():
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 0
  def hel(self):
     a=10
     self.b=20
     c=a+b
     print c
 def hw(self):
     d=10
     print d, self.b
```

Comment: Unless it's a mutable object.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Even if it is mutable, reference will be changed, right?

Comment: @thefourtheye: No. If you try that with a list, all instances will share a single list. You need to assign `self.b` in `__init__` in that case. It's probably good to do the same even with immutable objects.

Comment: @flora You are assigning value in `hel` only. Did you make a call to that function, before using `hw`?

Comment: @flora You asked for my skype id?!?